# Light Refraction, Biconcave Lense, Creating Rough Diagram to Explain to Child

Tags: refraction

I've read that the refraction of light at the boundary of a medium can be described as follows:

-a line of connected people marching.  one side of the line enters mud, and slows down.  This causes the non-mud side to pivot towards the slower side, which then causes the line to change direction.

I'm helping my 9 year old with a science fair poster diagram. It's not a super competitive science fair; it's more for kids to explore ideas and have fun.  In my ignorance I don't want to lead him too far astray.

In the draft diagram below, the yellow parallel lines are supposed to be the wavefront of light.

Box 1 is supposed to illustrate the bending of the wave as it enters the medium at an angle.

Box 2 is supposed to illustrate the second redirection of the wave as it exits the medium at an agle.

Questions:

-For a simple diagram, would the waves exiting the medium (box 2) keep their "bent" shape?  The diagram is supposed to reflect the exiting waves bending more at the second boundary than they do at the first boundary.

-Is the pivoting concept a good analogy to use?

Thank you.

[image: refraction illustration]